# Change color of the label in a Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How can I change the color of a field's label in Simple Form? Now it's black but I want it to be white.. I'm using scss.
I tried this code below but it's not working:

```
label {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;

  }
```

and html output of the field

```
<div class="form-group email optional user_email"><label class="email optional control-label" for="user_email">Email</label><input class="string email optional form-control" placeholder="user@domain.com" type="email" value="test@gmail.com" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div>
```

Comment: please add your html code

Comment: @AmolUdage <div class="form-group email optional user_email"><label class="email optional control-label" for="user_email">Email</label><input class="string email optional form-control" placeholder="user@domain.com" type="email" value="test@gmail.com" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div>

Comment: ok, then you should add styling for `control-label` class  & I think my below solution should aslo work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the [CSS specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). But, [from the documentation's example](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/examples), every `label` has the `control-label` class, so style it instead:

```
.control-label{
     color: white !important; // some color
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer. It's possible that you already have some styles that overrides this one. With `!important` it will only use those one.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. It's working now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

try adding separate class for `label` and then add `css` for that class

Example:

add class name as `label-style` and then add style like below

```
.label-style{
   color: white;
 }
```

Hope this will help :)